# cant install 64bit ubuntu server on lenovo m71e thinkcenter

Tags: boot, server, uefi

I tried to install the 64bit version of ubuntu server on my device and it would install properly but it wouldn't boot and simply wouldn't detect the system , the CPU is intel Pentium G630 and it has 2 gigs of ram
when i tried Yunohost 64bit it would have a problem about the efi partition not existing and basically HDD errors ,when i finally tried ubuntu server 32bit it worked but it isn't the version i need , any thoughts about what would be causing this weird problem (I changed the HDD and the same problem appears)

Comment: If only 2GB of RAM that is a bit light for modern Ubuntu. You may need a lightweight flavor.https://ubuntu.com/download/flavours
Light weight flavors:
Lubuntu, Xubuntu, Ubuntu MATE, Budgie My old laptop from 2006 with 1.5GB of RAM would not install  Ubuntu. I could install server. Was a bit surprised that Kubuntu which I use for desktop worked, it is more of a mid-weight flavor.  And it worked a lot better from an external SSD. I normally used external SSD for newer Windows laptop, to have Kubuntu on it.

Comment: id try a flavor and give an update

Comment: I perform QA on devices as old as from 2005; but I have no idea what you're asking about as you gave no specifics. You do mention Ubuntu & Server, 64-bit means little unless you're specific as to which 64-bit (amd64, arm64, ppc64el, riscv64 etc) thus user error hasn't been rule out, and you gave no clues as to what release or if you used something appropriate for your hardware.  Please be clear & specific with details  (modern 32-bit exists only for armhf (32-bit ARM) but I'd not expect that to run on intel pentium.

Comment: i used ubuntu-22.04.4-live-server-amd64 , i just tried lubuntu and it gave this error grub-install --target=x86_64-efi --efi-directory=/boot/efi --bootloader-id=ubuntu --force
returned error code 1.

Comment: Did you partition in advance and not include an ESP - efi system partition? For UEFI installs you really should use UEFI with gpt partitioning although Ubuntu will allow very old MBR(msdos) for UEFI.